# Which volumes are covered by Oregairu season 1 and 2?

Tags: oregairu

According to [this news article on ANN](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-04-16/my-teen-romantic-comedy-snafu-anime-gets-2nd-season), *Oregairu* is going to get a second anime season.

How many volumes have been covered by the first season? And which volumes will be animated in the second season?

Comment: The 1st season, according to its mangaupdates page (http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=88936), covers vol 1-6 from LN. Dunno for 2nd season tho, since vol 9 hasn't even came out (someone in the source you gave said it'll come out on Friday tho), means there's just 3 volumes left to be animated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E3%82%84%E3%81%AF%E3%82%8A%E4%BF%BA%E3%81%AE%E9%9D%92%E6%98%A5%E3%83%A9%E3%83%96%E3%82%B3%E3%83%A1%E3%81%AF%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A1%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82&oldid=74913452#%E5%90%84%E8%A9%B1%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88), **season 1 covers volume 1-6 + 6.5 + 7.5** and **season 2 covers 7-11 + 10.5**. Note that the light novel has already passed over volume 12.

> Season 1
>
> - Episode 1-3: Volume 1
> - Episode 4-5: Volume 2
> - Episode 6: Volume 3
> - Episode 7-8: Volume 4
> - Episode 9-10: Volume 5
> - Episode 11-12: Volume 6
> - Episode 13 (extra): Volume 6.5
> - OVA: Volume 7.5
>
> Season 2
>
> - Episode 1-2: Volume 7
> - Episode 3-5: Volume 8
> - Episode 6-10: Volume 9
> - Episode 10-11: Volume 10
> - Episode 12-13: Volume 11
> - OVA: Volume 10.5

---

Also, consider reading [Did OreGairu anime adapt the Light Novel closely?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/28489) for further information regarding the anime adaptation.

Answer (score 2):

The first season covers the first 6 volumes, and the second season will adapt volumes 7-11.

Source:
https://kyakka.wordpress.com/2015/06/12/oregairu-zoku-episode-12-and-13-synopses/

Answer (score 0):

Season 1 adapts volumes 1-6 while heavily omitting a lot of details, interactions, and important scenes. Volume 6.5, bonus track excluded, is condensed in episode 13. Presumably season 2 will adapt volumes 7-9.

From: https://kyakka.wordpress.com/